# I am not able to copy the entire binary file

Tags: c++, file, stl, binary, copy

```
    ifstream ifile("/home/zuma/xps.mp3", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ofstream ofile("/home/zuma/xxx.mp3", ios::binary | ios::out);

    copy(istream_iterator<unsigned char>(ifile), istream_iterator<unsigned char>(), ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(ofile));

    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();
```

The new file created has lesser bytes than the original one & the files do not match

Comment: Please add a short example of input and output.

Answer (score 5):

`istream_iterator` uses `operator>>`, which is whitespace delimited (and no, opening the file in binary mode does not change this behavior).  Use `istreambuf_iterator` instead.

```
istreambuf_iterator<char> in1(ifile), in2;
ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(ofile);
copy(in1, in2, out);
```

Or, as ildjarn mentioned, you can copy the whole file with much less typing:

```
ofile << ifile.rdbuf();
```

Comment: Even easier, `ofile << ifile.rdbuf();` -- no iterators necessary.

Comment: @ildjarn: Granted, but if he wants to adapt it to copy less than the whole file, that won't work.

Comment: @user643979 A good way to thank someone for a correct answer is to click the accept button. It highlights their response as the most useful (and gives a slight score boost, although I don't think Benjamin Lindley is hurting for it).